# Complex combinatoric database tree - many to many with variation pivot

Tags: database, laravel, relationship

I'll keep it short and brief. I've got two models: `Scheme` and `Feature` with a many to many relationship between them. What I want to achieve but don't know how is the following: I need a given value to be present in a database according to the features a scheme has. That means, for every possible combination of a scheme and all of the possible features, I want to have a particular value (in this case - an image to display for the scheme according to its features).
Example:

Scheme 1 has feature 1 - image 1;

Scheme 1 has feature 2 - image 2;

Scheme 1 has feature 1 and 2 - image 3

Scheme 1 has feature 1 and 3 - image 4 and so on.

What is the optimal db structure for that purpose? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at these two propositions and shoose.

[image]

Comment: You're proposing to set the image as a pivot attribute on a scheme-feature record and I get this. The problem is I need all possible variations with regard to the count and the id of the feature, that means that only one image per scheme-feature relation is by far insufficient. But thanks for the response and your effort!

Comment: and what about the second proposition?

Comment: Isn't it the same principle but disected into two separate tables?